# Is there a way to remove all line breaks which are in the middle of sentences?

Tags: editors, sourcecode

I have a lot of latex files in which line breaks have been used frequently.

The problem is that a lot of these line breaks is used to help the reader see a whole sentence of text on his screen like here:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit.
```

I would like to find a way to convert this into a sentence on only one line like here

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Are you talking about line breaks in the pdf output or in the `.tex` source file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information about your document setup. E.g.,  do you want to suppress line-breaking globally, or only for selected sentences? Will a non-breaking sentence always start on a new line? May it be assumed that the long sentences fit inside the text block, or do you anticipate that some non-breaking sentences run into the right-hand margin and possibly run off the page altogether?

Comment: why would you want to do that (it makes no difference to the output) but any editor ought to be able to do a regular expression replace of something like `([a-z]) *\n([a-z])` to `\1 \2` to replace newlines by spaces if they just have lowercase letters at end and start of the line.

Comment: Texworks has an ‘unwrap’ feature. You can load the document into that text editor, or use SED or similar utility. You can even load the document into MS Word or LibreOffice Writer, search for two paragraph signs (^p^p in Word) and replace them with a unique string (I use @@@@@), then search and replace all single paragraph marks with a space. Not fool proof, but works for most of my files.

Comment: @Sveinung Aside from the general inadvisability of using Word for this, that search and replace would replace just those newlines which the OP wants to retain, without touch any of the breaks s/he is trying to eliminate.

Comment: @cfr No, it will not, provide that this is a LaTeX-file where paragraph are marked by two line breaks/paragraph marks (^p^p). I forgot to explicit write that OP has to search for the the unique strings and replace them with two paragraph marks, but that goes without saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [`latexindent`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en).

Say you have the following file

## `myfile.tex`

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit.
```

and the `YAML` file

## `mathias.yaml`

```
modifyLineBreaks:
    removeParagraphLineBreaks:
        all: 1
```

and you run the command

```
latexindent.pl myfile.tex  -m -l mathias.yaml
```

then you should receive the following output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

`latexindent.pl` is customisable via the YAML interface, see the documentation for further options and examples.

Comment: Won't this remove breaks which are not mid-sentence, too, as long (guessing here) as they are mid-paragraph?

Comment: @cfr yes, that's correct